# Google's multi channel funnel php api is returning empty rows

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to get MCF data out of the API, but the only useful data I get are the total results for each of the two metrics. The rows are returned as null primitiveValues. The object also has property called "containsSampledData" which is set to false.

The question is:
How do I get the sampled data into the rows and why is the containsSampledData false at the moment?

the dates are 2020-02-01 to 2020-02-16

```
$optparams = array('dimensions' => 'mcf:adwordsKeyword', 'filters' => 'mcf:conversionType%3D%3DTransaction', 'max-results' => 100);
$ga_result = $analytics->data_mcf->get('ga:'.$VIEW_ID, $start_date, $end_date,'mcf:assistedconversions,mcf:lastinteractionconversions',$optparams);
```

the example of the response:

[image]

Comment: What dates are you requesting for and can we see an example of the response.

Comment: `
$start-date = 2020-02-01
$end-date = 2020-02-16
`

I will add the example asap in an edit.

Comment: apparently, it could be messed up because the view has filters on it.